# SQL check link between two records (CASE, WHEN, THEN)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I Have in table some records:

```
ID Services
2  A
2  C
2  C1
2  D2
```

I`m trying make query that will be select a link between services.

For example: If for ID 2 exists Services C then check if exist Service C1, result Yes or No.

```
SELECT a. ID, a.service,
CASE 
    WHEN (a.service ='C') = (a.service  = 'C1') THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
END      
FROM t1 a
```

Comment: Can you give more examples of different types of links, and what the result should be?

Comment: Link between services i shoud make manualy from services map. For example if in ID is service XZ1 then on ID must be service FU2. I have about 15-20 such links.

Comment: Can you post expected output with an example?

Comment: The expected result is showing all not linked servcies for a given ID.

`ID Services RESULT_LINK
2  A             No
2  D2           No`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE (t2.Services LIKE t1.Services + '%' OR
                         t1.Services LIKE t2.Services + '%') AND
                        t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.Services <> t2.Services);
```

This returns `A` and `D2` only.

### Demo

Comment: Good! But the services not always have +% in name :(. One linked service can be XYZ and ABC.

Comment: I have answered the exact question you posted.  If you are trying to establish a link between `ABC` and `XYZ`, two strings which have nothing in common, then you'd need to tell us how we can possibly know that any relationship exists.

Comment: This relations are determined by assumptions. Someone invented if on any ID's exists service ABC then must also be on this ID service XYZ if not then is wrong for "system", and now I trying find all ID's with no relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... what about this? But I now have problem with checking relationship for each ID independently...

```
SELECT a. ID, a.service,
CASE 
    WHEN a.service IN ('C','C1') THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
END      
FROM t1 a
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT ID,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN service = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
                  SUM(CASE WHEN service = 'C1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
             THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
        END) as c_c1_flag
FROM t1
GROUP BY ID;
```

The `SUM(CASE . . . )` counts the number of rows that match the conditions.  The `> 0` simply says that at least one row exists.